Front derailleur cable routing
I was trying to get the front gears changing correctly on a kiddies mtb I was given for my gd and I wondered Is the cable routed/connected correctly-please see image

Looks a bit wrong. Should be over the silver tab and then into the pinch bolt. Here is a picture of the similar derailleur with correct routing:

Other observations:

That cable is already very tired so try to keep amount of times you readjust it and clamp it to a minimum. It will only take so much before it has to be replaced

Cable end is not terminated correctly, it might catch on clothing or cut someone's leg. Consider putting a cable end cap on it. I am sure your local bike shop will give you one for free, they cost close to nothing.

Rear tire side wall is degraded and may be compromized



thanks that was the problem cable neededt to go over the tab!

Not sure that derailleur should have the cable going in on that angle.   Its possible the frame came with a different FD and its been changed.
If the bike came with a "top normal" front derailleur then it would be pulling toward the big chainring.
What you have appears to be a bottom-normal, so with no tension on the cable it pulls the cage toward the small chainring.
Given its a little kid's bike, making it one-by / single chainring is a solution.  All you have to do is remove the shifter cable, and use the limit screws to put the FD cage in a good spot.  Certainly the cheapest way forward.

Another solution might be to abandon using the brazed-on cable stop, and fit another one more "overhead"   There exist commercial clamp-on units like this one, or make your own with a Jubilee clip and some creativity.


I generally agree with you @Criggie, but look at the angle of the cable stop welded to the frame in OP's picture. It is welded at an angle and I am sure that is intended by frame designer. Or am I missing smth?

@ArtGertner yeah two possibilities there, either the front derailleur mech has been replaced at some point in the past, and the old one was "top normal" where the current mech is bottom normal, OR the bike builder didn't care and forced it together - perhaps knowing a kid's bike doesn't really change gear at the front much if ever.

The derailleur fitted is top-pull but the cable is clamped on the wrong side of the tab. Routing the cable over the tab gives the correct pull ratio for indexing.
